# Square root of $-1$ in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle(x^2+1)^2\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, hensels-lemma

Does there exist a square root of $-1$ in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle(x^2+1)^2\rangle$?

Now, any element in the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle(x^2+1)^2\rangle$ is of the form $(a+ib)+e(c+id)$ where $i^2=-1$ and $e^2=0$. Now, setting $a=c=d=0$ and $b=1$, I think we would get a square of $-1$. Is this right? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: @Qurultay actually I took inspiration from the way they usually write dual numbers, like the elements of the ring $\mathbb{R}/\langle x^2\rangle$. By the way could you say as to why there is no sqaure root of $-1$. Will $(a=bx+cx^2+dx^3)^2=-1$ not yield any solutions?

Comment: $(X^2+1)^2\mid \left[\frac12(X^2+1)X+X\right]^2+1$

Comment: @user26857 is correct. This is easily computed by Hensel's Lemma as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That a root *exists* is immediate from [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) (Newton's method). It is instructive to go futher and compute it by lifting the *obvious* root $\,x^2\equiv -1\pmod{p\! =\! x^2\!+\!1}\,$ up to $\!\bmod {p^2}.\,$ First we use the general Hensel lifting formula, then we solve it without assuming any knowledge of Hensel.

Note $\  y_1 \equiv\, x\,$ is a root of $\,f(y) = y^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{\!x^2\!+\!1}$

$\!\!\begin{align}{\rm thus}\ \ y_2 &\equiv\, y_1 - f(y_1)\left[\dfrac{1}{f'(y_1)}\bmod x^2\!+\!1\right]\\[.2em]
  &\equiv\, x - (x^2\!+\!1)\left[\,\dfrac{\color{#c00}1}{2\color{#c00}x}\ \ \, \bmod x^2\!+\!1 \right]\\[.2em]
&\equiv\, x - (x^2\!+\!1)\left[\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{-x}}{2}\right]\,\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ \color{#c00}{\dfrac{1}x}\equiv\dfrac{-x^2}x\equiv \color{#0a0}{-x}\!\!\!\pmod{\!x^2\!+\!1}
\end{align}$

hence $\,y\equiv (x^3+3x)/2\,$ is a root of $\,y^2\equiv -1\, \pmod{(x^2\!+\!1)^2},\, $ by Hensel.

---

**Remark** $ $ If Hensel's Lemma is unknown we can instead do the same directly. Let $\,p = x^2\!+\!1$.

$\!\!\bmod p\!:\ y \equiv a+bx\,$ so $\,-1 \equiv y^2\equiv a^2\!-\!b^2+2ab\,x$ $ \iff a=0,\, b=\pm1\iff y\equiv \pm x$

So, wlog we have: $\, y = x \!+\! g p\,$ for some $\,g\in \Bbb R[x].\,$ Lifting it up to $\!\bmod p^2\,$ we get

$\!\!\bmod p^2\!:\ {-}1\equiv y^2\equiv (x\!+\!gp)^2\equiv x^2\!+\!2xpg\!$ $\iff\! 2xpg\equiv -p\!$ $\iff\! \bmod p\!:\ g\equiv\large\frac{\color{#c00}{-1}}{2\color{#c00}x}\equiv \frac{\color{#0a0}x}2 $